# My website is on heroku and I'd like to integrate a blog into it. I tried Butter CMS but it is quite expensive. How should I approach this?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, heroku

I have an existing website that is built on Heroku. It's React on the front end and Node.Js on the back end. We need to add a blog to the website. I looked into ButterCMS and it seems very easy to use and it would take minutes to add it, but the pricing starts at $49, which seems too much at this stage.

So we basically need a new page that goes to www.mywebsite.com/blog and has a blog on that page. I think most headless CMS from what I read can be easy to integrate but not completely free. WordPress sounds too complex for the task.

Should I just add a page and add some blog-like features?

What would your approach be?
Keep in mind that it's also my first website and haven't experienced implementing something like this before.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using nodejs you can try strapi.io - very good solution. 
It helps you to build an easy REST API using cms. Try it :)